# What is maxlength of userid querystring in Bot Framework WebChat Iframe?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I went through documentation of Bot Framework but could not find maxlength of **userid** querystring.

Answer (score 0):

You can send any length to bot but the concept behind is a service call and The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer than the server can handle.

Check the below screen shot of emulator which is giving result for string length `3268300`

[image]